# Errors when using Typescript with Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to use Typescript in my Vue project. If I use the normal JS format it works correctly but if I want to use the `@Component` annotations it has numerous errors occur.

**Working**

```
<template>
  <div>Home</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

const x : number = 10

export default {
  name: "Home",
  tag: ""
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**Failing**

```
<template>
  <div>Home</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import Vue from 'vue';
import {Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default class Home extends Vue {

  @Prop()
  tag: string

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**Error**

```
[vue-component] Error while compiling in tag <script> using lang ts Format of the tsconfig is invalid: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 37
Error: Format of the tsconfig is invalid: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 37
at TypeScriptCompiler._parseConfig (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:289:13)
at TypeScriptCompiler._processConfig (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:263:32)
at TypeScriptCompiler.getBuildOptions (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:80:10)
at TypeScriptCompiler.processFilesForTarget (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:103:26)
at typescriptHandler (packages/vue-component-typescript/vue-typescript.js:27:24)
at packages/meteor.js:212:23
at VueComponentTagHandler.getResults (packages/vue-component/plugin/tag-handler.js:91:26)
at compileTags (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:532:18)
at compileOneFileWithContents (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:541:12)
at VueCompo.compileOneFile (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:140:12)
at packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:57:34
at C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3110:16
at replenish (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1011:17)
at C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1016:9
at Object.eachLimit$1 (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3196:24)
at VueCompo.processFilesForTarget (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:41:11)
at __bottom_mark__ (C:\tools\utils\parse-stack.js:69:14)
at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:210:27
at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:388:12)
at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:197:22
at Function.time (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\tool-env\tools\tool-env\profile.ts:284:12)
at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:196:15
at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:191:9)
at CompilerPluginProcessor.runCompilerPlugins (C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:186:7)
at ClientTarget._runCompilerPlugins (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1125:22)
at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:850:34
at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:388:12)
at ClientTarget.make (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:844:18)
at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3183:14
at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3334:25
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3288:14
  at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:283:5)
  at bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3164:31)
  at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3109:32
  at Slot.withValue (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\@wry\context\lib\context.js:73:29)
  at Object.withCache (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\fs\tools\fs\files.ts:1650:39)
  at Object.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3109:16)
  at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:572:24
  at Function.run (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\tool-env\tools\tool-env\profile.ts:289:14)
  at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:571:34)
  at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:613:35)
  at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:927:28)
  at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:401:12
  [vue-component] Error while compiling in tag <script> using lang ts Format of the tsconfig is invalid: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 37
    Error: Format of the tsconfig is invalid: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 37
    at TypeScriptCompiler._parseConfig (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:289:13)
    at TypeScriptCompiler._processConfig (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:263:32)
    at TypeScriptCompiler.getBuildOptions (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:80:10)
    at TypeScriptCompiler.processFilesForTarget (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:103:26)
    at typescriptHandler (packages/vue-component-typescript/vue-typescript.js:27:24)
    at packages/meteor.js:212:23
    at VueComponentTagHandler.getResults (packages/vue-component/plugin/tag-handler.js:91:26)
    at compileTags (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:532:18)
    at compileOneFileWithContents (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:541:12)
    at VueCompo.compileOneFile (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:140:12)
    at packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:57:34
    at C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3110:16
    at replenish (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1011:17)
    at C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1016:9
    at Object.eachLimit$1 (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3196:24)
    at VueCompo.processFilesForTarget (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:41:11)
    at __bottom_mark__ (C:\tools\utils\parse-stack.js:69:14)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:210:27
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:197:22
    at Function.time (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\tool-env\tools\tool-env\profile.ts:284:12)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:196:15
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:191:9)
    at CompilerPluginProcessor.runCompilerPlugins (C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:186:7)
    at ClientTarget._runCompilerPlugins (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1125:22)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:850:34
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at ClientTarget.make (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:844:18)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3183:14
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3334:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3288:14
      at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:283:5)
      at bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3164:31)
      at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3109:32
      at Slot.withValue (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\@wry\context\lib\context.js:73:29)
      at Object.withCache (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\fs\tools\fs\files.ts:1650:39)
      at Object.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3109:16)
      at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:572:24
      at Function.run (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\tool-env\tools\tool-env\profile.ts:289:14)
      at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:571:34)
      at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:613:35)
      at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:927:28)
      at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:401:12
      => Errors prevented startup:

      While processing files with akryum:vue-component (for target
      web.browser):
      packages/vue-component/plugin/utils.js:200:15: TemplatingTools is not
      defined
      at throwCompileError (packages/vue-component/plugin/utils.js:200:15)
      at VueComponentTagHandler.getResults
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/tag-handler.js:104:11)
      at compileTags (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:532:18)
      at compileOneFileWithContents
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:541:12)
      at VueCompo.compileOneFile
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:140:12)
      at packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:57:34
      at
      C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3110:16
      at replenish
      (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1011:17)
      at
      C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1016:9
      at Object.eachLimit$1
      (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3196:24)
      at VueCompo.processFilesForTarget
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:41:11)


      While processing files with akryum:vue-component (for target
      web.browser.legacy):
      packages/vue-component/plugin/utils.js:200:15: TemplatingTools is not
      defined
      at throwCompileError (packages/vue-component/plugin/utils.js:200:15)
      at VueComponentTagHandler.getResults
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/tag-handler.js:104:11)
      at compileTags (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:532:18)
      at compileOneFileWithContents
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:541:12)
      at VueCompo.compileOneFile
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:140:12)
      at packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:57:34
      at
      C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3110:16
      at replenish
      (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1011:17)
      at
      C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1016:9
      at Object.eachLimit$1
      (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-component\0.15.2\plugin.vue-component.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3196:24)
      at VueCompo.processFilesForTarget
      (packages/vue-component/plugin/vue-compiler.js:41:11)
```

I've tried using different formats I've found in tutorials but can't get them to work either. Here are some examples.

**1.**

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
}
```

**2.**

```
@component({
    name: 'HelloWorld'
})
```

**3.**

```
<script lang="typescript">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

let message: string;

@Component
class MyButton extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    message = 'world';
    console.log(`Hello, ${message}!`);
  }
}

// The export default has to be on a separate line due to the way the code is transpiled.
export default MyButton;
</script>
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Looks to me like something is reading `tsconfig.json` as json instead of jsonc, or it is simply invalid.

Comment: Did you install typescript ?

Comment: Typescript is installed. The working example has typescript in it and works fine.

Comment: In any case you would have better luck creating a new project with the cli and moving your pages

Comment: It looks like it's down to differences in Typescript versions so certain fields weren't allowed in the tsconfig. 
I would restart with a new project but I want to use Meteor and have spent the last 2 days trying to get it working. I've managed to get it somewhat working now by cloning an example project but it's been a big hassle.